# Create a Button to refresh other files without opening

Tags: javascript, java, html, qlikview, qliksense

I want to create an extension folder to refresh some other qvf files without opening those files by creating one button in current qvf file (what i will open daily in that file). For that I am not able to find / write `JS and QEXT` Programs.

Can anyone please help me for the Javascript, QEXT

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show some code you have tried by yourself.

Comment: Hi Franck, I haven't tried any code because till i din't use java script or html for this requirement i want to use java script. In my Qlik sense application we can create custom extensions by using java script for that custom extension creation i need this script.

Comment: Albeit such requests are "on topic" here, thing is: chances of getting helpful feedback are *much* better when you include own efforts. Meaning: research the topic, try solving the problem yourself. And then when you have some code, and a specific problem, write up a question about that.

Comment: Hi, Yeah I know that thing parallely i am doing that thing also.. but this is urgent requirement for me.... that's why i posted here. I want it by tomorrow end of the. that is the urgency... if any one know the solution give me the answer. Don't give this type of suggestions please because i don't have to give reply's also please understand

Comment: Sorry, but your priorities don't change *anything* about how this site works. If you want better, more helpful feedback *urgently*, then well: then you should have quickly improved your question. If you *want* something, you have to *invest* sometimes.

Comment: check out https://github.com/xtrimf/TaskRunner - it might help you figure it out or just use it....